# Angular view not updating after data deleted

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a blogging app that has a list of posts you can choose to edit, view or delete. If you click "delete," the post should be removed from the post management page. I can see the data be updated in the console to have one fewer posts after clicking "delete", but the number of posts on the page isn't updated until I refresh the page. I'm hoping someone can spot the disconnect between my controller and view.

#### server.js

```
router.delete('/api/posts/:post_id', function(req, res) {
    var results = [];

    // Grab data from the URL parameters
    var id = req.params.post_id;

    // Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
    pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
        // Handle connection errors
        if(err) {
          done();
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(500).json({ success: false, data: err});
        }

        // SQL Query > Delete Data
        client.query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=($1)", [id]);

        // SQL Query > Select Data
        var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC");

        // Stream results back one row at a time
        query.on('row', function(row) {
            results.push(row);
        });

        // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
        query.on('end', function() {
            done();
            return res.json(results);
        });
    });

}); 

module.exports = router;
```

#### controller.js

```
// Delete post
$scope.deletePost = function(postID) {
    $http.delete('/api/posts/' + postID)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.postData = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

#### manage.jade

(this is a partial template, let me know if you want to see layout.jade as well)

```
h1 Manage posts 
br
div(class="post-list")
  div(ng-repeat='post in postsData track by $index' class="post")
    h3 Title: {{ post.title }} 
    h3 Date: {{ post.published | date: 'MMM d, y'}}
    h4 Author: {{ post.author }}
    div Post: {{ post.draft }}
    div(class="edit-buttons")
      a(href="posts/{{ post.id }}")
        button(class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-success pull-left") View post
      a(href="posts/{{ post.id }}/edit")
        button(class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-info pull-left") Edit post
      button(class="btn btn-default  btn-lg btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="deletePost(post.id)") Delete post
```

Any thoughts on this greatly appreciated! I'm new to Angular, so let me know if I'm missing any best practices as well.

Comment: splice postsData array, no need to rebind the object is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postsData` on the view is not `postData` in the controller.

**Wrong Code:**

controller:

```
$scope.postData = data;
```

view:

```
'post in postsData track by $index'
```

Change `$scope.postData = data;` to `$scope.postsData = data;`

Also, since `.success`/`.error` is deprecated, change the code to use the `.then()` method like this:

```
$http.delete('/api/posts/' + postID).then(function(data) {
    //Success
    $scope.postsData = data;
    console.log(data);
}, function(data) {
    //Error
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
});
```

If, for some reason, you get data from outside of Angular (not applicable here), then you will need to "apply" the scope, so that the view updates. To do this, you need to run `$scope.$apply()` - although this normally causes more problems then it fixes. Most of the time, there are ways to do the same thing from within Angular (using angular's `$http` instead of JQuery - as you are already doing, etc)

Comment: I had hoped and feared it would be something that similar. Thank you very much for finding it!

Comment: @KatieBroida Very happy to help! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error. [Angular docs for $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

That means, you should write:

```
// Delete post
$scope.deletePost = function(postID) {
    $http.delete('/api/posts/' + postID)
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.postsData = response.data;
            console.log(data);
        }, function(response) {
            console.log('Error: ' + response);
        });
};
```

Angular promise resolution will cause a digest update, and your data will be visible.

Also, as others pointed out, you used different variable names in the controller and in the template. In the template you referenced `postsData`, but in the controller you've set `postData`.

Comment: Interesting, I think I'll go back and read more about this once I get this project working.